# Spring RestTemplate.execute(), how to stub the response that gets passed in to my callback function?

Tags: unit-testing, callback, mockito, resttemplate

I have the following code. Dictionary is just a wrapper for a List of type String.

```java
public Dictionary getDictionary(int size, String text) {
    return restTemplate.execute(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, response -> {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getBody()));
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            if (isMatch(line, size, text)){
                words.add(line.toLowerCase());
            }
        }
        br.close();
        return new Dictionary(words);
    });
}

private boolean isMatch(String word, int size, String text) {
    if(word.length() != size) {
        return false;
    }
    return wordUtil.isAnagram(word, text);
}
```

I'm having a hard time test this method at the moment. The HTTP call just returns a list of words in plain text with new line separators.

I want to write a test where I can stub the response.getBody().

I.e. I want response.getBody() to return a bunch of words, and I'll assert that the returned Dictionary only contains the words that are of size `size` and that are an anagram of the string `text`.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: `Dictionary is just a wrapper for a List of type String` This is so confusing. Even if it makes sense in your domain, consider renaming that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to stub a method taking a callback, and execute the callback when the stub is called.

The idea is to:

- use `when` / `thenAnswer` to execute code when the stubbed method is called
- use `invocationOnMock` passed to `thenAnswer` to get the callback instance
- call the callback, providing necessary params

```java
@Test
void testExecute() {
    String responseBody = "line1\nline2";
    InputStream responseBodyStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseBody.getBytes());
    ClientHttpResponse httpResponse = new MockClientHttpResponse(responseBodyStream, 200);
    when(restTemplate.execute(any(URI.class), eq(HttpMethod.GET), eq(null), any())).thenAnswer(
      invocationOnMock -> {
          ResponseExtractor<MyDictionary> responseExtractor = invocationOnMock.getArgument(3);
          return responseExtractor.extractData(httpResponse);
      }
    );
    MyDictionary ret = aController.getDictionary(1, "text");
    // assert ret against your expecations
}
```

Having said that, this seems to be a bit complicated for the task at hand. IMHO you will be better off if you separate the logic of dealing with Http from your business logic. Extract a method taking your inputStream, and test that separately.